# What is the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x]/(2x-3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is there a good description for the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x]/(2x-3)$?

That is, does the quotient ring $\Bbb Z[x]/(2x-3)$ isomorphic to some other ring with a simple description?

I know that $\Bbb Z[x]/(2x-3)$ is an integral domain since $2x-3$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$, so the quotient ring is indeed well defined. But I don't know if we can go further than that.

Answer (score 5):

$R=\Bbb Z[x]/(2x-3)\cong\Bbb Z[1/2]$ via the map which sends $x-1\mapsto 1/2$.

Then this is a subset of $\Bbb Q$, so $\text{frac}(R)\subseteq\Bbb Q$. However since $\Bbb Z\subseteq R$ we have that $\text{frac}(\Bbb Z)\subseteq\text{frac}(R)$, hence we have that $\text{frac}(R)=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I don't get the isomorphism.

Comment: I think I would understand it better with a surjective map $\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z[1/2]$ with kernel $(2x-3)$. What is this map?

Comment: $p(x) \mapsto p(\frac 32) \in \mathbb Z[1/2]$ should work. @user283386

Comment: @user283386 since $2x-3-0$ we have $2(x-1)-1=0$, so $x-1$ acts like 1/2, hence my choice of map. You can as easily say let the map be $x\mapsto 3/2$, I just chose $x-1$ instead.